# How can I open the Bootstrap Dropdown programmatically?

Tags: gwt, twitter-bootstrap

I develop the GWT application. Also I use Twitter Bootstrap library and GWTQuery. There is the `DropdownButton`. I want to open it programmatically.

ui.xml like this:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:b="urn:import:com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui"
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
...
<b:DropdownButton text="Test" ui:field="dropdownButton">
   <g:FlowPanel ui:field="contentPanel"/>
</b:DropdownButton>
```

I can open it via inspector of Google Chrome - add 'open' class to 'btn-group'. But it is impossible programmatically. I don't know why. Usages of `addClassName` / `addStyleName` methods are ignored.

Also I have tried to simulate click event via `Document.get().createClickEvent`, but the dropdown hasn't `handlerManager`. I have tried to call `trigger` and `click` with help of JQuery/GWTQuery.

Is it possible to open Dropdown programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try subclassing DropDownButton, adding a getter for the trigger button (at the end of the class), like this:

```
 public class CustomDropdownButton extends DropdownBase {

private Button trigger;

/**
 * Creates a DropdownButton without a caption.
 */
public CustomDropdownButton() {
    super("div");
    addStyleName("btn-group");
}

/**
 * Creates a DropdownButton with the given caption.
 * 
 * @param caption
 *            the button's caption
 */
public CustomDropdownButton(String caption) {
    this();
    setText(caption);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected IconAnchor createTrigger() {
    trigger = new Button();
    trigger.setCaret(true);
    return trigger;
}

/**
 * Sets the button's size.
 * 
 * @param size
 *            the button's size
 */
public void setSize(ButtonSize size) {
    trigger.setSize(size);
}

/**
 * Sets the button's type.
 * 
 * @param type
 *            the button's type
 */
public void setType(ButtonType type) {
    trigger.setType(type);
}

/**
 * Sets the button's icon.
 * 
 * @param type
 *            the icon's type
 */
@Override
public void setIcon(IconType type) {
    setBaseIcon(type);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void setBaseIcon(BaseIconType type) {
    trigger.setBaseIcon(type);
}

@Override
public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
    return trigger.addClickHandler(handler);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void setIconSize(IconSize size) {
    trigger.setIconSize(size);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void setCustomIconStyle(String customIconStyle) {
    trigger.setCustomIconStyle(customIconStyle);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void setIconPosition(IconPosition position) {
    trigger.setIconPosition(position);
}

public Button getButton(){
    return trigger;
}
```

}

Now you will have in your uiBinder xml :

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:b="urn:import:com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui"
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:c='urn:import:com.example.packageWithCustomDropDown'
...
<c:CustomDropdownButton text="Test" ui:field="dropdownButton">
   <g:FlowPanel ui:field="contentPanel"/>
</b:CustomDropdownButton>
```

And now you can call, the click function, on the button : `dropDownButton.getButton().click();`

I don't test it, but it should work.

Hope it helps. :)